# Attribute-based routing and handling of omitted querystring parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Assuming these models:

```
public class PagingModel
{
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }
}

public class FilterModel
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }
}
```

Assume standard routing (based on route mappings in WebApiConfig.cs) and a Web API controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] FilterModel filterModel, [FromUri] PagingModel paging)
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "filter=" + filterModel.Filter + ", skip=" + paging.Skip + ", take=" + paging.Take);
    }
}
```

If I hit http://localhost:12345/api/values (omitting the querystring parameters), this outputs "filter=, skip=0, paging=0" - thus the parameters are set to empty instances of FilterModel and PagingModel.

Now assume the same controller, but with attribute-based routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/testing")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] FilterModel filterModel, [FromUri] PagingModel paging)
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "filter=" + filterModel.Filter + ", skip=" + paging.Skip + ", take=" + paging.Take);
    }
}
```

If I now hit http://localhost:12345/api/testing (again, omitting the querystring parameters) I get a null reference exception - filterModel and paging are both set to null.

What causes this difference? Are the two routing mechanisms somehow using different ModelBinders ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo to me

In your second example, `filterModel.filter`, `paging.take` and `paging.skip` don't exist, causing the null reference exception.

Why ? Because it's Filter, Take and Skip according to your class declaration

Comment: That's a copying error, corrected. Nothing to do with the problem though.

Comment: Would adding [HttpGet] after [Route("")] help ? I am not sure about my suggestion but that's what [the web api documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) seems to indicate.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. It was worth a shot though :-)